# Correcting Namespace in entire project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

Originally few Forms were on the root folder of my Solution Explorer. Later I created a sub-folder and moved these Forms in that folder. Even though the application is working fine, but in few instances it gives NameSpace error.

Old Forms were like:

```
public partial class contentReportTubeMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
```

whereas, new forms have:

```
public partial class subFolderName_contentReportTubeMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
```

I am using VS-2005. Is there any built-in tool through which I can correct wrong namespaces of all entire project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using find and replace?

```
Ctrl + H
```

Comment: Any other automated refactoring method? CTRL + H may cause application breakdown if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Find&Replace tool (Ctrl+H). You can use `Regular Expressions` to match exactly what you want.